# not possible to register an object id with an object of the same type

Tags: fflib

I am registering two new accounts using the [fflib unit of work](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl/apex_patterns_sl_learn_uow_principles). The code as follows:

```
fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.unitOfWork.newInstance();

Account account1 = new Account(Name = 'Marketing account');
Account account2 = new Account(Name = 'Reebok account');

uow.registerNew(account1);
uow.registerNew(account2, Account.MarketingAccountId__c, account1);

uow.commitWork();
```

The field Account.MarketingAccountId__c is mandatory so it cannot be null, otherwise, Salesforce fails to insert/create the account. After issuing uow.commitWork() salesforce complains that account2.MarketingAccountId__c is null.

If the relationship would be other than Account then the unit of work runs properly and adds the related Id; however, if I do the exact same thing but relating an object of the same type, then the unit of work fails and sets a null value.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? If this is the expected behavior of the unit of work, how do you tackle this issue?

Comment: It looks like it may be a bug since I see this issue reported on their Github repo. https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/issues/279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported and you can see why by considering pure APEX:

```
Account account1 = new Account(Name = 'Marketing account');
Account account2 = new Account(Name = 'Reebok account', MarketingAccountId__c = account1.Id);
insert new List<Account> {account1, account2};
```

The above is what you are asking the `fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork` to do - execute one statement that creates a hierarchical relationship between two sobjects of the same SObjectType before the ID of the first object is known.

If you look at the code for `fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork`, you'll see there is no provision for creating dependency graphs with multiple DML operations on the same SobjectType.

The [workaround in the GitHub issue](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/issues/279) (use two units of work) is the only solution.

From the Salesforce Lightning Platform Enterprise Architecture 3rd edition page 181

> **Unit of Work special considerations**
>
> Use cases not supported:
>
> Self and recursive referencing (your use case)
>
> More granular DML operations (Database allorNothing = false)